# how to empty (or reset) an edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Say the user answers a mathematical question, then he moves on to answer the next one. What statement do you use to empty the EditText?

i.e. 1 + 1 = 2, 2 is still in the EditText when the equation is now 3 + 3.

If I haven't made myself clear please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the text to `""`:

```
editText.setText("");
```

Comment: I'll leave it anyway hehe, maybe someone will stroll through these woods and find this answer which he was seeking. :P